# After installing Jira, I get the error Failed to start jira.service: Unit jira.service not found after a reboot

Tags: jira

I successfully installed and used Jira on an Azure VM running CentOS.  To save on costs, the server shuts down at night.  When it came up the next day, I logged in to start Jira and I got the error:

> Failed to start jira.service: Unit jira.service not found

Anybody have any idea why this would be the case?  I checked /opt and everything was there, so I know that the software was still installed.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having this issue, I found a page that seemed to fix it.  Even though I chose to install Jira as a service, it did not create the jira.service file.

Here is how to fix this problem:  https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/run-jira-as-a-systemd-service-on-linux-979411854.html